# Search for specific user name only in comments where "@" character was left out

Tags: support, search

Can I search for a specific user name where other users forget to put a `@` character in front of it, but only in superuser comments?

Maybe via [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new) since it provides a comment property?

I thought of a query similar to this pseudocode:

```
select * questions where comment_text = "* nixda*"
```

(Searching for names in questions/answers does work without problems.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created this [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/146090/find-all-comments-where-your-name-is-mentioned-but-doesnt-contain-an?UserName=nixda) which will search through all comments for a username anywhere in the text, but without the @reply.

Just enter the desired username in the parameter box & you're good to go.

<sub>thanks Tim for the nudge!</sub>